# Hover and on click effects on Image Map

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created an Image Map with 6 circles. I am trying to add hover effect on each circle.

Also added Jquery to display different content on clicking each image. It's working fine. But I also want display default content on page load, which is not working.

I have added the code here.

Can you help me on that?

```js
function codeAddress() {
    $('.whyt').html($('.why-us').html());
}

window.onload = codeAddress;

document.getElementsByClassName( "p5" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.why-us').html());
};

document.getElementsByClassName( "p6" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.seo').html());
};

document.getElementsByClassName( "p7" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.ranking').html());
};

document.getElementsByClassName( "p8" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.benefits').html());
};

document.getElementsByClassName( "p9" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.quality').html());
};

document.getElementsByClassName( "p10" )[0].onclick = function(){
    $('.whyt').html($('.faq').html());
};
```

```css
#map14 area:hover {
    background: url('https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SEO_Icon.png');
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="why-img" src="https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/wp-content/themes/smg/Images/Why_Us.png" alt="" usemap="#map14">

             <map id="map14" name="map14">

             <area shape="rect" coords="289,8,407,126" title="" alt="" href="#tt1" class="p5">
             <area shape="rect" coords="17,18,116,117" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p6">
             <area shape="rect" coords="144,201,246,305" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p7">
             <area shape="rect" coords="403,283,498,380" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p8">
             <area shape="rect" coords="235,403,332,503" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p9">
             <area shape="rect" coords="16,403,116,503" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p10">

             </map>
         <div class="col-sm-6 whyt">                 
                 <a name="tt1"></a>             
     </div>
     
     <div style="display:none;">   
     
            <div class="why-us">
              <h3>Why Us</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    
    <div class="seo">
              <h3>SEO</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    
    <div class="ranking">
              <h3>Page 1 Rankings</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    
    <div class="benefits">
              <h3>Benefits</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    
    <div class="quality">
              <h3>Quality</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    
    <div class="faq">
              <h3>FAQ</h3>   
             <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
  Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
   making it work for them. </p>
   <br/>
   <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a>
             </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply hover effect on image map area. I did a trick to apply the hover effect on image map area. Just apply the trick on rest image map area.

Please check.

```js
   

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.p6').mouseover(function(){
  
  $(".nav-wrap span.backer").css({"background":"url('https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SEO_Icon.png')","z-index":"999"});
   
  });
 
 $('.why-img').mouseout(function(){
  $(".nav-wrap span.backer").css({"background":"none","z-index":"100"}); 
 });
 
 
 $('.whyt').html($('.why-us').html());


 $(".p5").click(function(){
  $('.whyt').html($('.why-us').html());
 });


 $(".p6").click(function(){
     $(".nav-wrap span.backer").css({"background":"url('https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SEO_Icon.png')","z-index":"999"});

   $('.whyt').html($('.seo').html());
 });

 $(".p7").click(function(){
  $('.whyt').html($('.ranking').html());
 });

 $(".p8").click(function(){
  $('.whyt').html($('.benefits').html());
 });

 $(".p9").click(function(){
  $('.whyt').html($('.quality').html());
 });
 
 
 $(".p10").click(function(){
  $('.whyt').html($('.faq').html());
 });
 
});
```

```css
  

.backer { display:block; width:135px; height:129px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:-1; }
.nav-wrap { display:block; position:relative; }
.nav-wrap area { display:block; }
.why-img { position:relative; z-index:200; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="nav-wrap"> <span class="backer"></span> <img class="why-img" src="https://searchmgseo.com.au/smg/wp-content/themes/smg/Images/Why_Us.png" alt="" usemap="#map14">
  <map id="map14" name="map14">
    <area shape="rect" coords="289,8,407,126" title="" alt="" href="#tt1" class="p5">
    <area shape="rect" coords="17,18,116,117" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p6">
    <area shape="rect" coords="144,201,246,305" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p7">
    <area shape="rect" coords="403,283,498,380" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p8">
    <area shape="rect" coords="235,403,332,503" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p9">
    <area shape="rect" coords="16,403,116,503" title="" alt=""  href="#tt1" class="p10">
  </map>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 whyt"> <a name="tt1"></a> </div>
<div style="display:none;">
  <div class="why-us">
    <h3>Why Us</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
  <div class="seo">
    <h3>SEO</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
  <div class="ranking">
    <h3>Page 1 Rankings</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
  <div class="benefits">
    <h3>Benefits</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
  <div class="quality">
    <h3>Quality</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
  <div class="faq">
    <h3>FAQ</h3>
    <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
      Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
      making it work for them. </p>
    <br/>
    <a href="" class="btn-md">Get Quote </a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine here. But not working on my website and in fiddle. Can you please check> <http://jsfiddle.net/guptaasargam/uc1haczt/1/>

Comment: You can chop icons separately instead of image map, and set them using position absolute CSS.

HTML markup should as follows:

`<div class="icons-wrapper">
 
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
    


 <div class="icon1"> 
     <a href="#">icon1</a>
    </div>

 <div class="icon2"> 
     <a href="#">icon1</a>
    </div>


 <div class="icon3"> 
     <a href="#">icon1</a>
    </div>


 <div class="icon4"> 
     <a href="#">icon1</a>
    </div>


</div>`

Comment: Please create a fiddle which you have done so far. So I can check what's the problem exactly.